# Express + Typescript. Call controller from another controller

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

So I have a controller which I want to call from another controller. As you can see I trying to pass parameter `{params: {task_id: String(task_id), result}}`, but typescript complains that `res` doesn't have all attributes. How can I make it?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you encapsulate the common logic in another function (which's not a controller but a service) and use it in both `getCommentById` and `getCommentsSocketListener`.

Every controller needs a response and request object and there's no good way of skipping it.